# For independent, symmetric random variables $(\xi_n)$, $E\left(\left(\sum\limits_n\xi_n\right)^2\land1\right)\le\sum\limits_nE(\xi_n^2\land1)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expectation

The following problem appears as an exercise in the Russian version of *Probability*, Shiryaev, 2003 edition(it seems that no English version containing this problem is available yet).

> Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$ be independent, symmetrically distributed random variables. Then
>   $$\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_n\xi_n\right)^2\land1 \right)\le\sum_n\mathsf E(\xi_n^2\land1)$$

---

To avoid discussing convergence issue, I would like to assume that the summation is finite. It's not quite clear from context what "symmetrically distributed" means, but it's reasonable to guess this means $\xi_n$ and $-\xi_n$ has the same distribution. In this sense, I tried to write,
$$\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\xi_n\right)^2\land1 \right)=\int(x^2\land1)dF_{S_N}(x)=2\int_0^\infty(x^2\land1)dF_{S_N}(x)$$
and
$$\mathsf E(\xi_n^2\land1)=\int(x^2\land1)dF_{\xi_n}(x)=2\int_0^\infty(x^2\land1)dF_{\xi_n}(x)$$
and, after integrating by parts, reduce the problem to proving
$$\int_0^1x\left(\mathsf P(S_N\ge x)-\sum_{n=1}^N\mathsf P(\xi_n\ge x)\right)dx\le0$$
The problem would be settled if
$$\mathsf P\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\xi_n\ge x\right)\le\sum_{n=1}^N\mathsf P(\xi_n\ge x),\quad 0\le x\le1$$
which is, unfortunately, not true in general.

---

**My question:** Is my approach above completely nonsense? Is it possible to turn it into a proof? If not, how to prove this inequality?

---

**Edit.** By induction, it suffices to prove for $N=2$, i.e. $\mathsf E((\xi_1+\xi_2)^2\land1)\le\mathsf E(\xi_1^2\land1)+\mathsf E(\xi_2^2\land1)$. This should be easier, but still not quite obvious for me.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks for your reply. I've thought about this, but what Jenson inequality implies seems to differ from the original inequality by some $1/n$ here and there.

Comment: @macavity: $x^2$ is convex but $1 \wedge x$ is concave, no?

Comment: @shalop Yes, one would have to look at the composition. Not so easy then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how/if one can make your proof idea into a proper proof, but you can prove the result as follows:

First note that if $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed in $\{1,-1\}$, then for any $a_1,\dots,a_n \in \Bbb{R}$, we have
$\Bbb{E} \sum_i \omega_i a_i = 0$, and hence
$$
\Bbb{E} \left(\sum_i \omega_i a_i\right)^2
= \mathrm{Var} \sum_i \omega_i a_i 
= \sum_i a_i^2 .
$$
Also note that $\Bbb{E} f(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n) = 2^{-n} \sum_{\omega_1, \dots , \omega_n \in \{1,-1\}}  f(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n) $ is just a finite sum.

Next, note for arbitrary (fixed) $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n$ that $(\omega_1 \xi_1, \dots, \omega_n \xi_n )$ has the same distribution as $(\omega_1, \dots,\omega_n)$, by symmetry and independence.

Finally, for any random variable $X$, it is not hard to see $\Bbb{E} [X \wedge 1] \leq 1 \wedge \Bbb{E} X$.

All in all, this shows
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}_\xi \left[\left( \sum_i \xi_i \right)^2 \wedge 1 \right]
&= \Bbb{E}_\omega \Bbb{E}_\xi \left[\left( \sum_i \omega_i \xi_i \right)^2 \wedge 1 \right] \\
& =\Bbb{E}_\xi \Bbb{E}_\omega  \left[\left( \sum_i \omega_i \xi_i \right)^2 \wedge 1 \right] \\
&\leq \Bbb{E}_\xi \left[1 \wedge \Bbb{E}_\omega \left(\sum_i \omega_i \xi_i \right)^2 \right] \\
&= \Bbb{E}_\xi \left[1\wedge \sum_i \xi_i^2\right] \leq \Bbb{E}_\xi \sum_i (1\wedge \xi_i^2) ,
\end{align}
which easily implies the claim.

Comment: +1 Very nice! Where does the idea of introducing the auxiliary $\omega$ come from?

Comment: @CaveJohnson: Thanks, I also like the argument, although now it seems that it is somewhat more complicated than needed. Concerning the $\omega_i$: For me, the main problem in proving the estimate was to "pull in" the square into the sum. And this you can achieve using the $\omega_i$. In this context, if you don't know it already you should have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality. Finally, I think I have seen a similar argument in the book "A mathematical introduction to compressive sensing" by Rauhut.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with the following much simpler argument: $$E\left\{\left(\sum {\xi_i}\right)^{2}  \wedge 1 \right\} \leq \left\{E\left(\sum \xi_i\right)^{2}\right\}\wedge 1\ = \left\{\sum E(\xi_i)^{2}\right\} \wedge1 \leq \sum \left\{E(\xi_i)^{2} \wedge 1\right\}$$ where we have used the fact that $E\xi_i \xi_j =0$ for $i \neq j$?

Incidentally, if one of the variables has infinite expectation the inequality becomes trivial.

I have also used the fact that $$\left\{\sum a_i^{2}\right\} \wedge1 \leq \sum \{a_i^{2} \wedge 1\}$$ for all non-negative numbers $a_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. The problem is that $\mathsf E(\xi_i\xi_j)$ may not exist at all, so I think there is something more to prove here.

Comment: Nice argument! So, for your proof it seems that you don't even need the symmetry of the $\xi_i$. It seems that it suffices to know that each $\xi_i$ has zero expectation.

Comment: When I said infinite expectation I meant infinite second moment. There is no loss of generality in assuming that $E\xi_i^{2} <\infty$ for all i and therefore $E\xi_i \xi_j$ does exist. My proof is complete. The hypothesis that $\xi_i$'s are independent and symmetric can be replaced by the hypothesis that $E\xi_i \xi_j =0$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Maybe I am being stupid, but it's not immediately clear to me that $\mathsf E\xi_i^2=\infty$ for some $i$ would trivialize the original inequality. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: It is enough to prove the inequality for finite number of $\xi_i$'s because Monotone Convergence Theorem can be used to prove it for infinitely many variables. A simple application of Fatou's Lemma allows us to reduce the proof to the case where the random variables are uniformly bounded: multiply $\xi_i$ by the indicator of $\{|\xi_i| \leq N\}$. Sorry that I left out these details in the first write-up. The main point of my proof is that no tricky argument (like introducing new variables and conditioning) is necessary.

Comment: @Cave Johnson, the first proof of PhoemueX also assumed existence of second moments. So the arguments involving Monotone Convergence Theorem and Fatoou's Lemma are needed there too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now. But it seems that without symmetry, truncating by $|\xi_i|\le N$ would break $\mathsf E(\xi_i\xi_j)=0$, i.e. $\mathsf E(\xi_i\xi_j1_{|\xi_i|,|\xi_j|\le N})=(\mathsf E (\xi_i1_{|\xi_i|\le N}))^2$ may not be $0$. I'm not sure whether a proper way truncating would resolve this. By the way, the proof by PhoemueX does not assume the existence of second moments of $\xi_i$, if you read it carefully.

Comment: @Cave Johnson you are right. So my proof also requires independent and symmetric random variables.